# Powershell Invoke-Command remotely with -AsJob failed to launch remote program

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, powershell-jobs

I want to launch a long-running remote program but don't want to wait. So I put below one line command in PS script file and run "Powershell -file xxx.ps1"

```
Invoke-command server1 {xxx.exe} -AsJob
```

But the remote program is not running after the script run, but if I run above command in PS console interactively, remote program running ok. Seems the program is killed when script terminates.

Why is this?

**UPDATE**

If I sleep 1 second at end of script, the remote app running fine.

Answer (score 1):

The best way around this is probably to use [Wait-Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849735.aspx). It will wait for the job you launched until it's done. Otherwise the script just closes, probably before the connection has already been made completely.

If you want to wait for all jobs running in the background to be completed, you can use:

```
Invoke-command server1 {xxx.exe} -AsJob
Get-Job | Wait-Job
```